# Constrained relativistic particle under distance dependent force

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, potential-energy

I found this question while browsing for special relativity problems. There are no solutions and I am quite lost on how to proceed with it.

> A relativistic particle of mass $m$ is bound to move along the x axis under the action of a conservative force whose potential energy is $V (x) = γx^4$, where $γ> 0$ is a dimensional parameter.
>
> The maximum distance from the origin reached by the particle is $d$. Determine the speed $v_0$ with which
> the particle passes through the origin. Under what condition on $d$ do we recover the classic result for $v_0$?

Comment: Hint: The particle reaches its maximum distance when it has zero kinetic energy. When the particle crosses the origin, it has zero potential energy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write the equation of motion first. Using $F=-\frac{\mathrm{d}V(x)}{\mathrm{d}x}$, and the relativistic form of Newton's second law, the equation of motion is $$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} \Bigg( \frac{m\dot{x}}{\sqrt{1-\frac{\dot{x}^2}{c^2}}} \Bigg)=-4\gamma x^3.$$ You can check by yourself that the following quantity is a constant of motion, $$E=\frac{mc^2}{\sqrt{1-\frac{\dot{x}^2}{c^2}}}+\gamma x^4. $$ Then use this fact to solve for the velocity, you should get $$\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t}=c \sqrt{1-\frac{m^2c^4}{(E-\gamma x^4)^2}}$$ Now, separate variables and integrate, $$\int\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt{1-\frac{m^2c^4}{(E-\gamma x^4)^2}}}=ct.$$ You can now use this fact to predict various features of the motion like its **maximum distance**, its period and others.